# Settings and accessing a pointer from concurrent goroutines

Tags: go

I have a map which is used by goroutine A and replaced once in a time in goroutine B. By replacement I mean:

```
var a map[T]N

// uses the map
func goroutineA() {
    for (...) {
        tempA = a
        ..uses tempA in some way...
    }
}

//refreshes the map
func gorountineB() {
    for (...) {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Seconds)
        otherTempA = make(map[T]N)
        ...initializes other tempA....
        a = otherTempA 
    }
}
```

Do you see any problem in this pseudo code? (in terms of concurrecy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code isn't safe, since assignments and reads to a pointer value are not guaranteed to be atomic. This can mean that as one goroutine writes the new pointer value, the other may see a mix of bytes from the old and new value, which will cause your program to die in a nasty way. Another thing that may happen is that since there's no synchronisation in your code, the compiler may notice that nothing can change a in goroutineA, and lift the `tempA := a` statement out of the loop. This will mean that you'll never see new map assignments as the other goroutine updates them.

You can use `go test -race` to find these sorts of problems automatically.

One solution is to lock all access to the map with a mutex.

You may wish to read the [Go Memory Model](http://golang.org/ref/mem) document, which explains clearly when changes to variables are visible inside goroutines.

Answer (score 3):

When unsure about data races, run `go run -race file.go`, that being said, yes there will be a race.

The easiest way to fix that is using a [sync.RWMutex](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) :

```
var a map[T]N
var lk sync.RWMutex
// uses the map
func goroutineA() {
    for (...) {
        lk.RLock()
        //actions on a
        lk.RUnlock()
    }
}

//refreshes the map
func gorountineB() {
    for (...) {
        otherTempA = make(map[T]N)
        //...initializes other tempA....
        lk.Lock()
        a = otherTempA
        lk.Unlock()
    }
}
```